# ATMEGA328p-AU BootLoader

Tags: arduino, atmega, bootloader, atmega328p

I have ATMEGA328P-AU chip, to burn the bootloader I used ARDUINO Uno Board as "ARDUINO as ISP" with setup Board: Nanno. I'm getting the following error. While looking for the solution I got suggestions of

1. rechecking the connection - Yes I did
2. Lower the Buad Rate - Tried observed the same result as below
3. Tried varying the external oscillator 8MHz/ 16Mhz
   The command to upload the bootloader is as follow:

> D:\WorkSpace\Arduino\arduino-1.8.7\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CD:\WorkSpace\Arduino\arduino-1.8.7\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM9 -b19200 -e -Ulock:w:0x3F:m -Uefuse:w:0xFD:m -Uhfuse:w:0xDA:m -Ulfuse:w:0xFF:m

I want to know the does this signature 0xffffff indicates I have blown out the IC similar ???

> ```
>      Using Port                    : COM9
>      Using Programmer              : arduino
>      Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200 avrdude: stk50
> ```
>
> 0_recv(): programmer is not responding avrdude: stk500_getsync()
>   attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x8e
>            AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
>            Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
>            PAGEL                         : PD7
>            BS2                           : PC2
>            RESET disposition             : dedicated
>            RETRY pulse                   : SCK
>            serial program mode           : yes
>            parallel program mode         : yes
>            Timeout                       : 200
>            StabDelay                     : 100
>            CmdexeDelay                   : 25
>            SyncLoops                     : 32
>            ByteDelay                     : 0
>            PollIndex                     : 3
>            PollValue                     : 0x53
>            Memory Detail                 :
>
> ```
>                               Block Poll               Page                       Polled
>        Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
>        ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
>        eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
>        flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
>        lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
>        hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
>        efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
>        lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
>        calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
>        signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
>
>      Programmer Type : Arduino
>      Description     : Arduino
>      Hardware Version: 2
>      Firmware Version: 1.18
>      Topcard         : Unknown
>      Vtarget         : 0.0 V
>      Varef           : 0.0 V
>      Oscillator      : Off
>      SCK period      : 0.1 us
> ```
>
> avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
>
> Reading | ################################################## | 100%
>   0.00s
>
> avrdude: Device signature = 0xffffff (probably .avr8x_mega) (retrying)
>
> Reading | ################################################## | 100%
>   0.01s
>
> avrdude: Device signature = 0xffffff (probably .avr8x_mega) (retrying)
>
> Reading | ################################################## | 100%
>   0.00s
>
> avrdude: Device signature = 0xffffff (probably .avr8x_mega) avrdude:
>   Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
>            Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
>            this check. avrdude done.  Thank you.

Comment: You need to use the exact baud rate for the bootloader you flashed, the correct clock source, the correct command, the correct serial connection, to trigger reset at the correct time... Essentially none of the critically key information is in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..added the command

Comment: Still too much missing.  Maybe try writing a sketch that does endless unprompted serial output ideally with brief pauses, upload that with the ISP and make sure you can read the output before you add all the additional complications of the bootloader communication.  Once that works you can try uploading a bootloader again, informed by everything you learned about the situation.

Comment: sorry, I'm not getting you specifically "Maybe try writing a sketch that does endless unprompted serial output ideally with brief pauses", I used this link for the above procedure https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard

Comment: A bootloader is not required to load a sketch, and a boot loader requires more to work right than a sketch that merely does output does.  So start with such a sketch, use "upload via programmer" (or whatever they are calling that menu option now) and get that producing serial output you can capture, first.  In doing that, you can help yourself vs. saying that you followed the instructions but the result does not work does not make a question answerable here.

Comment: I have a fresh chip so for that, I need to upload the bootloader first n then the code on serial, I'm struggling with bootloader

Comment: Okay I got your point, I tried to upload basic blink code with following command:D:\WorkSpace\Arduino\arduino-1.8.7\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CD:\WorkSpace\Arduino\arduino-1.8.7\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM12 -b9600 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_701939/Blink.ino.hex:i 
Result: avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x86

Comment: Then your problem is an ISP problem, not a bootloader problem...   Look at the source of the Arduino ISP sketch and see what baud rate is used.  Make sure your did the reset modification.  Double check your wiring and `edit` clear documentation of it into your question.

Comment: would clarify little more and the solution for the same as well; Does all sync error lands to ISP fault?

Comment: Sync error is typically communication *with* the programmer, device signature is typically communication *between* the programmer and the *target*.  You've now reported both in different experiments...

Comment: okay thanks a lot!! so I need to change the code uploader board right??

Comment: I have a doubt regarding boot loading, Can u clarify this line "However you must have in mind that the Upload Using Programmer procedure doesn't burn fuses so if you have a fresh factory micro-controller you have to burn the boot-loader first in order to have a properly working device." from this link- https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Programmer and u asked me to upload the code directly, it's bit confusing

Comment: ARGH, like a lot of Arduino documentation, that is horrible.  What they probably mean is to "borrow" the fact the burning a bootloader also sets fuses.  You aren't actually using the bootloader (once you erase as part of trying to load anything else it is gone anyway), just the side effect that the process does the fuses too, and those persist.

Comment: Okay, Does that mean "the code upload (UART comm) necessory fuses are set under bootloading", which one can do without bootloading as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of time on the bootload uploading using Arduino as an ISP, I switched to USBASP. And successfully uploaded the code on those suspicious IC, which I kept aside considering dead. Though I could not figure out the fault in Arduino while uploading, I would suggest doing the same if someone stumbled at a similar question.

Comment: This is a fairly random solution, but please accept your self-answer so that the question shows as resolved and does not continually get churned back up.